# SonarQube - DotNet - FxCop issue

Tags: .net, fxcop

I am using Sonar 3.4.1 and when trying to analyze the DotNet Project, I am getting ‘null’ value in the dashboard for folders and File names.

fxcop-report.xml generated by fxCop tool have  tag in the XML file and by default it should have attributes (Certainty, Level, Path, File, Line). But for some of the issues it has only (Certainty & Level) attributes. Please check and let me know why the other attributes are not there in  tag.

Also fxcop-report.xml there is a below exception, please let me know whether this might cause the issue in the Fxcop-report.xml.

```
<Exception Keyword="CA0060" Kind="Engine" TreatAsWarning="True">
<Type>Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.FxCopException</Type>
<ExceptionMessage>
The indirectly-referenced assembly 'VBIDE, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ee34b28a434d7478' could not be found.
This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results could be incomplete.
This assembly was referenced by: E:\CCAP_Demo\DotNet\MAH_CHARLIE_Print_Application\source\Print\bin\Debug\Word.dll.
</ExceptionMessage>
</Exception>
```

Answer (score 0):

> it should have attributes (Certainty, Level, Path, File, Line). But
>   for some of the issues it has only (Certainty & Level) attributes.

FxCop uses information from the PDB file for providing location information.  However, the PDB only contains information that would be useful for debugging scenarios, which means that FxCop rule violations that are associated with non-executable code (e.g.: interface definitions) will not have location information in the report.

> Also fxcop-report.xml there is a below exception, please let me know
>   whether this might cause the issue in the Fxcop-report.xml

When FxCop runs, it can't find the VBIDE assembly.  You can use the sonar.fxcop.assemblyDependencyDirectories property to specify the location where it can be found when the sonar-runner executes.